# Im designing my webpage and was wondering if anyone can tell me how this sidebar on the left got here and possibly how to get rid of it in CSS

Tags: html, css

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>
      
      <!--Font Link-->
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      <!--CSS-->
      <link href="SQIStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <title>Solarquake Studios</title>
      <!--favicon-->
      <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" sizes="128x128" href="Logo.ico"/>

      <style>


      </style>
      
    </head>

    <h1>SolarQuake Studios</h1>

    <header>
      <img src="Logo.ico" alt="logo" width="80" height="80">
    </header>
    
    <body>


      <div class="container">
           <div class="left-col">
               <div class="scroll-bg">
                    <div class="scroll-div">
                     <div class="scroll-object">
                      <h3><u>Games</u></h3>
                      <p>Upcoming Projects</p>
                      <p></p>
                     </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
    
           </div>

           <div class="center-col">
               <div class="scroll-bg">
                    <div class="scroll-div">
                     <div class="scroll-object">
                      <h3><u>Esports</u></h3>
                      <p>The Hog Pen</p>
                     </div>
                    </div>
              </div>
           </div>

           <div class="right-col">
               <div class="scroll-bg">
                    <div class="scroll-div">
                     <div class="scroll-object">
                      <h3><u>Assets</u></h3>
                      <p>Game Art & Designs</p>
                     </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
           </div>

      </div>

      <div class="footer">
        &copy; All Rights Reserved.

        <p class ="secondary">Follow Us!</p>

        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UChQzAj3OlDO3sqZl7frbY7g"><img src="YTLogo.png" 
         width="70" 
         height="70" 
         alt="logo"></a>

        <a href="https://twitter.com/SQdevelopers"><img src="Twitterlogo.png" 
         width="64" 
         height="64" 
         alt="logo"></a>

      </div>
      
    </body>

</html>
```

The sidebar on the left wasn't intended to be here, I've played with container for these columns and the scroll-Div, scroll-BG, and scroll-object classes and haven't gotten anywhere. This is all my css code so far. Thanks in advance.

```
h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 62px;
    font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
    text-align: center;
    color: yellow;
    
}

h2 {

    font-size: 40px;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;

}

h3 {

    color: white;

}

header {

    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}



.container div {
    
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-height: 250px;
    margin-left: 6.5%;

}

.left-col {
    
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    color: floralwhite;   
    

}

.right-col {

    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    color: floralwhite;

}

.center-col {

    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    color: floralwhite;
    
}

.footer {

     clear: both;
     text-align: center;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     padding-top: 5px;
     color: yellow;
     font-size: 7px;

}


body {

    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url("Space.png");

}

.scroll-bg {

    background-color: yellow;
    width: 375px;
    margin: 10% auto;
    text-align: center;
    

}

.scroll-div {
    
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    text-align: center;

}

.scroll-object {

    color: white;
    font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    
}
```

I tried to remove the sidebar on the left, Its yellow. I cant find in my code where its coming from.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkRdd.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The yellow sidebar is there because you have a div with a class="scroll-bg"
So, remove the scroll-bg section from your css and its reference from your html.

```
### Remove ####
.scroll-bg {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 375px;
    margin: 10% auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Working example - https://jsbin.com/wubuqolumo/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

what a mess.

You are pushing every div from left by giving it a margin of 6.5%.
Change .container div(means every div inside container will have a 6.5% marging from left) to .container and remove margin. And add left right margin in every col class.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).